# Qualcomm Augmented Reality for non Snapdragon devices

Tags: android, augmented-reality, galaxy, tegra

Dose the Qualcomm AR support non Snapdragon devices (specifically galaxy S 2)?

I'm asking because I want to buy a Samsung Galaxy s 2 which has NVIDIA Tegra2, 
at the same time I want to make an AR app using Qualcomm AR on it.

Comment: The S II doesn't have a Tegra 2. There are three variants, one with Samsung's Exynos 4 SoC, one with TI's OMAP 4430, and one with a Snapdragon S3. The Tegra 2 version is called a Galaxy R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QCAR SDK performs an explicit check on the device compatibility and fails to initialize if it is not. So if your device isn't listed, and doesn't have a snapdragon processor, it's not going to work regardless of whether it's capable from a processing basis.

You can confirm this on the QCAR dev forum.
https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/forums

Answer (score 0):

They have a [list of supported](https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/support_file/download/supported%20devices/Supported_Devices.pdf) devices on their website...

Comment: but what about new devices?there is a lot of new devices.i need to know if anyone tried galaxy s2 specifically

Comment: If you have doubts based on chipset, you can go through the list and verify whether all of the entries are Snapdragons.  Since the handset you want is not supported, though, my guess is that you won't know if it'll do the things you want until you try.